# CSS not recognizing all selectors

Tags: html, css

I have some html and css, and I'm trying to get rid of the blue color and underline for the anchor tag

```css
#title-bar {
    background-color: rgba(34, 70, 136, 0.87);
    color: black;
    font-size: 3em;
}

a { 
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    color: inherit
}

a:hover { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: inherit; 
}

a:focus {
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: inherit; 
}
```

```html
<div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row justify-content-center' id='title-bar'>
        <a href="/"><h1>Home Page</h1></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The background-color works fine and so does the a and a:visited color, but the a:hover doesn't for some reason. It still goes blue and underlined when I hover over. Weirdly, when I add "style='text-decoration: none' " to the anchor tag, the underline goes away. Does anybody know how to get rid of the hover decorations?

Comment: you code works fine, can you edit the question to make it clear what the issue is?

Comment: It's weird that it works on StackOverflows' snippet but not locally on my machine. This is where my frustration is coming from. For whatever, reason, it won't render properly on my end.

Answer (score -1):

You have `color:inherit` which just uses the user-agent's default color. And `text-decoration:none` is working fine for me.

```css
a,a:visited,a:hover{
  color:black;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Click</a>
```